# The river....with aluminum and other things

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice

The river....with aluminum and other things.

A) have been polluted

B)has polluted

C)may be polluted

D)polluted

Comment: Hi, @Sajjad, right now it isn't clear from the question what you're asking. Could you edit your question to give more context, like where the multiple-choice question came from, what specifically you're unsure about, and why you selected the option you did?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A is not correct because "the river" is singular and "have" is plural. You can't say "The river have ...", you'd have to say "The river has ..." or "The rivers have ..."

B is not correct, or at least unlikely, because it is active voice. The river has done this. But it's very unlikely that the river is doing the polluting. More likely the polluting is being done to the river. It's possible, though. Maybe in context the writer means that the river is carrying pollutants to the lake or the ocean, so the river is doing the polluting. But probably not.

C is valid and correct. It is passive voice, so it is the river being polluted and not the river polluting something else.

D is the same issue as B. It's active voice, so it means the river did the polluting, which is unlikely.